# Is it possible to map <C-;> to : in vim?

Tags: vim

I use capslock as control so it is more natural to use  as `:` but `noremap <C-;> :` does not work. Is it possible to do such mapping in vim?

Comment: I recommend just mapping `;` to `:`. Personally, I much prefer not having to hold down shift, and `;` is not an overly useful motion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [Vim FAQ](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/vimfaq.html) (also available through [this nice plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3298)):

```
20.4. I am not able to create a mapping for the <xxx> key. What is wrong?

1) First make sure, the key is passed correctly to Vim. To determine if
   this is the case, put Vim in Insert mode and then hit Ctrl-V (or
   Ctrl-Q if your Ctrl-V is remapped to the paste operation (e.g. on
   Windows if you are using the mswin.vim script file) followed by your
   key.

   If nothing appears in the buffer (and assuming that you have
   'showcmd' on, ^V remains displayed near the bottom right of the Vim
   screen), then Vim doesn't get your key correctly and there is nothing
   to be done, other than selecting a different key for your mapping or
   using GVim, which should recognise the key correctly.
```

Trying the above with `<C-;>` shows that it is not captured by vim/gvim...

Comment: If you're running vim in a terminal (xterm, for example), there is no distinct <kbd>control-;</kbd> character.  Typing <kdb>control-;</kdb> just gives me a `;`.  As the FAQ says, things might be different if you're using the `gvim` GUI (but I never use it myself).

Comment: One addition: for all ascii characters `<C-{c}>`'s codepoint is equal to `char2nr({c})-0x40` and thus `<C-{c}>` for characters that have codepoints less then `0x40` can't be expressed in a vim's byte queue format and so can't be recognized by vim. Last character that can be expressed in this format is `0x5F`: `0x5F-0x40=0x1F`, `0x1F+0x01=0x20` and `0x20` is a space. So there are only `0x20` (32) `<C-...>` combinations recognized by vim. It may change in the future if someone changes used byte queue format.